# Looking for a Gauge Control library with markers

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I am working on a charting application, and looking for a HTML5/javascript gauge control

library that would:

1. have hovering functionality, or at least a readable legend.
2. have the option to add a marker with text to show average/trend value.
3. no needle.

something like the following picture, without a needle.

[image]

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/metormote/6392996 and then figure how to remove the needle :-)